# How we can remigrate data from M1 =>M2

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, data-migration-tool, delta-migration

I have done M1=>M2 data migration via Magento default tool and now I need for remigrate latest data from M1 to M2. Please let me know how can i do this.

Means, Firstly we have done data migrate from M1 to M2
secondly after some time we have to remigrate latest data from M1 to M2 on same platform.

Comment: one note is, delta migration till now is only for orders, customers profile changes, customer reviews. so no product, categories .. etc updates check https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/migration/migration-migrate-delta.html#overview

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have completed delta migratio. Thanks this is worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `php bin/magento migrate:delta {<path to config.xml>}` command to migrate incremental date from Magento 1 to Magento 2.

For more information, please see the below link.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-migrate-delta.html

Comment: hi @Pritam, yes i used delta migration, data transferred successfully, but command still running, its not stopping..

Comment: Hi @Jafar It is how Delta Migration works.  Because on live store orders, customers and other entities are created constantly and the migration tool in delta mode will catch it and migrate on the fly every 5 sec. Please see https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/4

Comment: okay @Pritam. its still running even after typing ctrl c, how to stop this?

Comment: You may edit configuration xml  in vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/ folder and set "host", "name","user" field value to empty under "source" XML entity.

Comment: hi @Pritam, We can't sure when to edit the file? so is there any other possiblities?

Comment: can we use M1 db different it was earlier means suppose we migration m1_db.sql of a site in m2 but now we have another store in m1_db_1.sql different site's db and imprt this also into M2 will be any issue during migration only products,customers and orders entities.